# Bash script and escaping special characters in password

Tags: bash, scripts, password

I have been reading a lot of questions already asked here, however, somehow nothing is working for me. I have a bash script where I have to send password which dump database on remote machine, so its like :

```
!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost mysqldump -u db_user -p#8111*@uu( my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz
```

Now thing is that this password has all sorts of special character: 
`#8111*@uu(`

If I run above command directly in shall using password inside single quotes then it works : ie.

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost mysqldump -u db_user -p'#8111*@uu(' my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz
```

Without single quotes I get error with for the '(' at end.

I also tried to escape characters in password like this :

```
!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost mysqldump -u db_user -p'\#8111\*\@uu(' my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz
```

Then it gives access denied error.

I also tried to use "source" ie. saving password in another file as :

File pass.cre

```
MYPASSWORD='#8111*@uu('
```

Then including that file in bash script:

```
!/bin/sh
source pass.cre
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost mysqldump -u db_user -p$MYPASSWORD my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz
```

It appears to be reading $MYPASSWORD from file then again error of invalid character.

Any advice what I am missing ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use double quotes twice, escaped and not escaped: `-p"\"$MYPASSWORD\""`

```
#!/bin/sh
source pass.cre
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost 'mysqldump -u db_user -p"\"$MYPASSWORD\"" my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz'
```

Or an other version

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost "mysqldump -u db_user -p\"'io#bc@14@9$#jf7AZlk99'\" my_database | gzip -c > my_database.sql.gz"
```

---

*Examples*

```
% source pass.cre
% ssh user@host mysqldump -u root -p$MYPASSWORD    
user@host's password: 
zsh:1: bad pattern: -p#8111*@uu(

% source pass.cre
% ssh user@host mysqldump -u root -p"$MYPASSWORD"   
user@host's password: 
zsh:1: bad pattern: -p#8111*@uu(

% source pass.cre
% ssh user@host mysqldump -u root -p"\"$MYPASSWORD\""
user@host's password: 
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

Comment: Thanks @meuh and A.B. , it certainly makes sense and I have tested it, its working. Thanks guys for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: There seems to be a little problem , I have password like this :
`io#bc@14@9$#jf7AZlk99`

For remote , its not working ie.
    `/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost "mysqldump -u db_user -p'io#bc@14@9$#jf7AZlk99' my_database |  gzip -c >  my_database.sql.gz"`

I tried to escape as suggested here ie. keeping in mind that its been executed twice but I think when sending command via SSH to remote server, things appears to be little changed.

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost "mysqldump -u db_user -p\"'io#bc@14@9$#jf7AZlk99'\" my_database | gzip -c > my_database.sql.gz"`

Comment: @Rick_IRS see my edit to my answer as you have a problem with `$#` and need single quotes throughout.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your string is being interpreted twice, once by the
local shell, and again by the remote shell which `ssh` is running for you.
So you need to quote twice, using either of these:

```
-p\''#8111*@uu('\'
-p"'#8111*@uu('"
```

**Edit:**
If you are going to double-quote `""` the entire command, you will have
problems with passwords containing `$`.  You need to single-quote the
command to avoid this. But you still need to single quote the `-p` value as
it is interpreted twice.  So you need single quotes inside single quotes.

This is done by use a **single quoted quote** (`\'`) as in this example:

```
'I don'\''t like java'
```

will give you the string `I don't like java`. 
So your double-quoted example becomes the single-quoted:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -p 91899 user@remoteHost 'mysqldump -u db_user -p'\''io#bc@14@9$#jf7AZlk99'\''my_database | gzip -c > my_database.sql.gz'
```

Don't you just love it?